# Does it matter which way a door is facing in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Depending on which way I'm facing when I place a door, it will either be on one side of a cube border or another. Are there any game mechanics that make use of the door's alignment which I should be aware of, or is it purely cosmetic?

*Door placed from this side*
[image: Door outside]

*Door placed from opposite side*
[image: Door inside]

Comment: Do we need a door tag?

Comment: @Ullallulloo: Not really. It was an attempt to make the site [the #1 reference for everything door related](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/485987#485987).

Comment: I think that [Home Improvement](http://diy.stackexchange.com/) would be better suited for that. :p

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe doors allow attacks in one direction. So if you mount the door from the *outside*, you can attack through it, but you cannot be attacked (or be shot by skeletons) from outside.

I can't find an official source on this, but [this thread](http://forums.redstonewire.com/viewtopic.php?p=392889#p392889) discusses it (see the last post), and [this blog entry](http://hubpages.com/hub/dont-do-these-things-please) (see number 5) seems to confirm it.

Comment: This information is indeed in the links provided, but let's have it all in one place: The correct placement of the door is from outside.

Comment: If you place a door from the outside, you can attack from the inside. I find this the most useful.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true anymore. As of the latest patch, left-clicking opens doors, so attacking through the door will open it.... probably not what you intended to do.

Comment: Just tested this in the new version. If you stand in the square which the door swings through, and stand flush with the door, you can attack through it normally without opening.

Comment: It's not "one way", the door is considered part of the whole block, and if you're "in" the block, attacks against the door hit *in that block* (where you are). If the enemy is in that block however, attacks "through" the door will hit it. @tylerl, you can still shoot arrows at it.

Comment: One of the "X's adventure in minecraft" video also shows the same thing

Answer (score 2):

The direction of the door dictates where it will be (and obstruct) when it is open. In cases where safety is not an issue, just convenience, I place doors such that they open onto the side of the opening that I am less likely to run into.

Answer (score 1):

I think it affects the direction the door opens. Although I am not sure if the door opens away from you as you place it or towards you.

This can be important if there is a mob on the other side of your door. If it opens towards the mob then you can safely bash them through the door. If it opens towards you then you might accidnetally open the door and let them in!

Comment: Doors open towards you, as you were standing when you placed it. The top picture opens towards me.

Answer (score 1):

You can't place a block on the same spaces as a door. However, you can wall up a door from the other side.

In context with your pictures, it's the difference between being able to place a block on the dirt square in front of the door. You shouldn't be able to in the first, but you can in the second.

The block in question also determines which way the door "swings" when you click it.